# Comparing Each Character in Java String

Tags: c++, iequalitycomparer

I am a beginner at C++, and I am trying to create two strings

any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you should compare the `String#substring(int, int)` instead.

Comment: Is word order important? You've shown that "super" and "perfect" result in "superfect", would "perfect" and "super" also be "superfect" or " perfectsuper"?

Comment: nope, the order is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Equals method will not help you in this situation. compare using charAt(). Use two for loop and iterate both strings then add not matching characters to one string and print it at last.
ex:

```
 for(int i=0;i&lt;inputword.length;i++){

       for(int j=0;i&lt;inputword2.length;j++){ 

          if(inputword.chatAt(i)==inputword2.charAt(j)){
               //here write your logic or remove it from your string
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: For(int i=0;i<inputword.length;i++){For(int j=0;i<inputword2.length;j++){ if(inputword.chatAt(i)==inputword2.charAt(j)){//here write your logic or remove it from your string}}}

Comment: I had to define by using char, but i think it would work! thank you

Comment: Code looks ok. At which line your getting exception.

Comment: Run it in debugging mode and find what goes wrong and change it.

Comment: I'm really a beginner in java so I have no idea about debugging..

I did try to do it with a compiler, but it doesn't work

it seems to be a simple code, and do you think you could write it?

Comment: Yes, i will post it later.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate how many characters at the start one word "overlap" the end of second:

```
public static int combinedLength(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 1; i < s1.length() && i < s2.length(); i++)
        if (s1.endsWith(s2.substring(0, i+1)) || s2.endsWith(s1.substring(0, i+1)))
            return s1.length() + s2.length() - i;
    return s1.length() + s2.length();
}
```

This works by progressively testing longer letter sequences at the start/end if find if s1 starts with s2's end or visa versa. Because there can be only one such match, the first match found returns the result of the sum of both lengths minus the iteration number. No match returns the sum of both lengths.

Testing:

```
combinedLength("super", "perfect") ==> 9
combinedLength("perfect", "super") ==> 9
combinedLength("pencil", "eraser") ==> 12
```